# Intelligently fetch text between two characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
(a(b(p(m()()))))
```

And want to retrieve the substrings:

```
a(b(p(m()())))
b(p(m()()))
p(m()())
m()()
```

Arbitrarily fetching the text between the encapsulating parentheses would result in something like:

```
a(b(p(m(
```

This is how I'm planning out the function to handle this:

```
def get_encapsulated_text(s):
    t = ''
    it = cycle(s)
    count = 0
    for c in it:
        if c is '(':
            print(c)
            while count != 0:
                t += next(it)
                print(t)
                nxt = next(it)
                if nxt is '(':
                    count += 1
                elif nxt is ')':
                    count -= 1
```

But it obviously enters an infinite loop and I'm no Pythonista. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I'd like to have it work against a more complicated example, like this:

```
(x(q(y(w()())(k()()))())(a(z()())(d(f()())())))
```

with an expected output of something like:

```
['x(q(y(w()())(k()()))())(a(z()())(d(f()())()))', 'q(y(w()())(k()()))()', 'y(w()())(k()())', 'w()()', 'k()()', 'a(z()())(d(f()())())', 'z()()', 'd(f()())()', 'f()()']
```

Comment: Because it's nested, you'll likely want to use `str.split('(', 1)` and `str.rsplit(')', 1)` to isolate your data.

Comment: Why not `m()` as well?

Comment: Sure that can be tacked on as well. I was just trying to helpfully illustrate the concept.

Comment: `(x(q(y(w()())(k()()))())(a(z()())(d(f()())())))` what is the expected output for this

Comment: I would use a variable that increments when encountering '(' and decrements when encountering ')', this way you can find the "matching brackets". I'd probably also use a bit of recursion.

Comment: @cryptonome See the latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_components(string):
    pairs, comps = [], []
    for i, c in enumerate(string):
        if c == "(":
            pairs.append([i,])
        elif c == ")":
            for p in reversed(pairs):
                if len(p) < 2:
                    p.append(i)
                    comps.insert(0, string[p[0]+1:p[1]])
                    break
    return [x for x in comps if len(x) > 0]
```

Comment: I'd add `if not not substr:` before adding the substring to `comps` to avoid the empty strings.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the extra iteration cycle, yet have something that's similar in "cleanliness?"

Comment: I'm sure it could be more concise, but now it only transverses `string` once.

Comment: Your updated version reverses the whole output string though. Is there a way to get what your initial version returned while having the efficiency of this version?

Comment: Yeah, use `.insert()` instead of `.append()`; see above.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_encapsulated_text(text):
    stack = []
    for c in text:
        if c == ')':
            inner = stack.pop()
            if inner:
                yield ''.join(inner)
        for s in stack:
            s.append(c)
        if c == '(':
            stack.append([])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strings = '(a(b(p(m()()))))'
charset = '((((()()))))'

result = []
bisected = len(charset) //2
for i, c in enumerate(strings):
    if c not in charset:
        sub = strings[i: (bisected + len(charset_len) - i + 1)]
        result.append(sub)

print(result)
# ['a(b(p(m()()))))', 'b(p(m()()))))', 'p(m()()))', 'm()()']
```

Comment: * check my latest edit for a better challenge: this breaks down

Comment: this breaks because the rule & pattern changed

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_substrings(string):
    string = string[1:len(string)-1]
    substrings = []
    while not (')' in string[:3]):
        substrings.append(string)
        string = string[2:len(string)-1]
    return substrings

string = "(a(b(p(m()()))))"
print(get_substrings(string))

#Output: ['a(b(p(m()())))', 'b(p(m()()))', 'p(m()())']
```

Comment: * check my latest edit for a better challenge: this breaks down

Comment: Could you answer cryptonome's question about what the expected output should be for the more complicated string?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough sketch. I would set an increment variable.

```
increment = 1
```

Then I'd iterate through the string, starting at `a` (after the first bracket). Everytime I encounter '(' I add 1, everytime I encounter ')' I subtract 1. When I meet 0, I know I have the matching bracket.

```
(a(b(p(m()()))))
1^2 3 4 54543210
```

Once I have that, I can take out the stuff between the brackets (that I now know the positions of).

```
a(b(p(m()())))
```

Then I would recursively call the same function, and perform the same steps. Then append the output of that recursive call into the strings that I have.

```
a(b(p(m()())))
 1^2 3 4343210
```

We can try this on `m()()`

```
m()()
 1010
```

In this case, it would give us two pairs of matching brackets. For a more complicated example,

```
x(q(y(w()())(k()()))())(a(z()())(d(f()())()))
 1^2 3 434323 4343212101 2 323212 3 434323210
```

Now it can intelligently find `q(y(w()())(k()()))()` and `a(z()())(d(f()())())` in there.

Edit: I figured I should type something out

```
def get_encapsulated_text(s):
    count = 0
    t = ""
    for c in s:
      if count != 0:
        t += c
      if c is '(':
        count += 1
      elif c is ')':
        count -= 1;
        if count == 0:
          output = t[:-1]
          t = ""
          if(output != ""):
            print(output)
            get_encapsulated_text(output)
```

I think the key here is just recursion.